# How to create Full screen Overlay Navigation using angular-material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I'm using angular material with angular5 and angular flex-layout, and I was looking for a similar [full screen overlay window](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp) angular component, but it seems like they didn't implement a one yet, and since I prefer consuming time on working on functionality rather than accessory component, I decided to ask you guys to share an example about it in "angular way" (if you already coded it).

Comment: The Material team has abstracted common behaviors into the @angular/cdk (component development kit). It's separate from Material, but Material implements it frequently. Check out the overlay component: https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview      Also check the source of things like `mat-dialog` to see how they've implemented it.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

Answer (score 7):

You can use MatDialog and make it full screen by including MatDialogConfig properties:

```
width: '100vw',
height:  '100vh',
maxWidth: '100vw',
maxHeight: '100vh',
hasBackdrop: false,
```

See [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6gyng?embed=1&file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts).

Comment: the width and maxWidth need to be 100vw , not 100vh. Otherwise great.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this [site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner).

It provides screenoverlay along with multiple type of spinners.
Moreover if you want to close the screen overlay then refer to this stackblitz which implements the above screen overlay.

[stackblitz llink](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etbk6k)